# Flash Player can't find XML configuration file

Tags: flash, configuration, iis-7.5, access-denied

We have a site that a client is bringing back to our servers after making the decision a while ago to outsource it to India.

One of their pages uses an SWF player to play some video. The SWF object in the page is apparently configured using an XML file. Here is the SWF code in the ASPX page:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0"
    width="900" height="600" id="tech" align="middle">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="movie" value="/Images/flv/simple.swf?xml_path=/Client/XML/NFLNews.xml" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <embed src="/Images/flv/simple.swf?xml_path=/Client/XML/NFLNews.xml" quality="high"
        wmode="transparent" width="900" height="600" name="tech" align="middle" 
        allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" allowfullscreen="true" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Notice the `embed` tag has a src property of:
    `src="/Images/flv/simple.swf?xml_path=/Client/XML/NFLNews.xml"`

When clicking on this page, it throws an "Access Denied" error on the file `/Client/XML/NFLNews.xml`. However if I browse directly to the XML file, IIS serves it up without error.

Here is what the IIS logs show for the request:
`#Fields:  date time cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-contentpath sc-status`
`2012-11-28 16:09:33.482 /Videodisplay.aspx VID=22 "X:\inetpub\wwwroot\sitename\Videodisplay.aspx" 500`

Note that Videodisplay.aspx is the page which hosts the SWF object. The XML file does not show up in the IIS logs at all.

Th exact error being thrown by IIS is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Access to the path 'F:\inetpub\wwwroot\lijsoccer.com\Client\XML\NFLNews.xml' is denied.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'F:\inetpub\wwwroot\lijsoccer.com\Client\XML\NFLNews.xml' is denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.
```

I'm assuming the SWF object must run under a different security context then than IIS does? 
Or is there something else going on here? We've never really dealt with Flash stuff here, so I'm all new to this.

Windows 2008 R2, ASP.NET 4,  IIS 7.5

**UPDATE:** I have determined by giving `Everyone` first **Read** then **Modify** access to the XML file that the SWF is actually modifying the XML file. Obviously I'd rather not leave EVERYONE having access to this file, so I added an auditing entry to the file for "everyone fail anything" to try to find out what user the SWF file is running under ... but even though removing the write permission from everyone DID cause it to fail again, it did NOT write a security audit event. So I guess for now I am stuck leaving Everyone with Write access to this file, unless someone can tell me how to determine which user the SWF is running under.

Comment: Some ideas to help troubleshoot: Might want to use an HTTP sniffer, Firebug, etc. to verify what path Flash is using to access that XML. Make sure you are using a debug version of Flash player (w/out it exceptions that occur at runtime will just fail silently w/out any indication).  What do the web server logs show when attempting to download the XML? Perhaps the SWF uses ExternalInterface and relies on some Javascript to parse the xml path?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It was actually finding the right file, ... the physical path IIS was showing in the error was correct. I've narrowed it down to that the SWF is modifying the file, so needed WRITE access. For now I've been forced to give Everyone WRITE access on this file.